# For each $a \in \mathbb{C}$, solve the complex equation $e^z = a$ (that is, determine all complex numbers $z$ such that $e^z = a$).

Tags: complex-analysis

> For each $a \in \mathbb{C}$, solve the complex equation $e^z = a$ (that is, determine all complex numbers $z$ such that $e^z = a$).

I have $e^{x+iy} = e^x \, (\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$. If $a = 0+0i$, then $e^x \, \cos(y) = 0$, $e^x \, \sin(y) = 0$.  As $e^x$ doesn't equal $0$, therefore $\cos(y) = 0$ and $\sin(y) = 0$. What do I do next?

Comment: The post needs to be typeset.

Comment: Look up [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)

Comment: If a = 0 + 0i, then no such z exists. You're trying to find z not a.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for any real $y$, $(\cos y)^2 + (\sin y)^2 = 1$. What does that tell you about a supposed $y$ such that $\cos y = \sin y = 0$? *Try to answer for yourself before revealing the spoiler.*

> Since $0^2 + 0^2 = 0 \neq 1$, there is no such $y$. In other words, $a = 0$ is not in the range of the function $f(z) = e^z$.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the natural logarithm of the complex number $a$, which does exist for any $a\neq 0$ (in fact, there are infinitely many for any such $a$). Read on to find out how to find them.

The first thing to be aware of is that the result of an expression of the form $e^{x+iy}$ is another complex number, which you can think of in two parts; first, the exponentiation of $e$ by $x$ (which will always be a real number). Then, if $e^x$ is viewed as a vector parallel to the $x$-axis (with its origin at $(0,0)$), the effect of multiplying it by $e^{iy}$ is to rotate it by $y$ radians in an anticlockwise direction about $(0,0)$. In short, it's nothing but a combination of real exponentiation and trigonometry! In this way, all conplex numbers except $0$ have at least one complex logarithm - even the purely real negative numbers!

Now, let $a=u+iv$, where $u$ and $v$ are not both equal to $0$. The magnitude of $a$ is of course equal to $(u^2+v^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. We need the natural log of this, which is equal to $\frac{\operatorname{ln}(u^2+v^2)}{2}$. This will play the role of "$x$" as outlined in the previous paragraph. For our "$y$", recall that it is the angle between our complex number and the positive $x$-axis in radians, measured anticlockwise. It is therefore equal to $\operatorname{atan}(\frac{v}{u})$.

Putting it all together, we have $e^z=e^{\frac{\operatorname{ln}(u^2+v^2)}{2}+i\cdot\operatorname{atan}(\frac{v}{u})}$. This means of course that $z=\frac{\operatorname{ln}(u^2+v^2)}{2}+i\cdot\operatorname{atan}(\frac{v}{u})$. But wait! I said that there are infinitely many logarithms for any nonzero complex number, and so there are; considering rotation, it should be clear that any extra positive (or negative) multiple of $2\pi$ added to the "base" angle will result in the same complex number. The full answer is therefore $z=\frac{\operatorname{ln}(u^2+v^2)}{2}+i\cdot(\operatorname{atan}(\frac{v}{u})+2k\pi)$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $u\neq 0$.

**Addendum**: in the case where $u=0$, we have two subcases: if $v\lt 0$, then $z=\frac{\operatorname{ln}(u^2+v^2)}{2}+i\cdot(\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$. If $v\gt 0$, then $z=\frac{\operatorname{ln}(u^2+v^2)}{2}+i\cdot(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the complex number $~a~$ equals $~b + ic,~$ where $~b,c \in \Bbb{R}.$

As others have responded, in order to determine $~z \in \Bbb{C}~$ such that $~e^z = a,~$ it is necessary and sufficient that $~a \neq 0.~$  This implies that at least one or the two variables, $~b,c~$ is not equal to $~0.~$

The first thing to do is determine $~r,\theta ~: ~r \in \Bbb{R^+}, ~\theta \in \Bbb{R},~$ such that

$$~a = b + ic = re^{i\theta} = r \times [~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta) ~].$$

To accomplish this:

- define $~\displaystyle r = \sqrt{b^2 + c^2}.$ 
  Since at least one of $~b,c~$ is not equal to $~0,~$ you are guaranteed that $~r~$ will be positive.
- then re-express $~b + ic~$ as $~\displaystyle r \times \left[ ~\frac{b}{r} + i\frac{c}{r} ~\right].$ 
  Note that from the specification for $~r,~$ you must have that 
  $\displaystyle \left( ~\frac{b}{r} ~\right)^2 + \left( ~\frac{c}{r} ~\right)^2 = 1.~$
- So, there must exist exactly one real number $~\theta,~$ within a modulus of $~2\pi,~$ such that $~\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{b}{r}, ~\sin(\theta) = \frac{c}{r}.~$ 
  So, you can choose any half open interval of length $~2\pi,~$ such as $~[0,2\pi),~$ or $~(-\pi,\pi],~$ or any other such interval that you choose, and find the unique satisfying real number $~\theta~$ in this interval.
- So, at this point, you will have successfully expressed $~a,~$ in the polar coordinates $~re^{i\theta}.~$ This implies that **one of** the satisfying values for $~z~$ will be $~\ln(r) + i\theta,~$ where $~\ln(r)~$ represents the natural log of the positive number $~r.$

At this point, you are almost done.  Given any real number $~\theta,~$ and any integer (positive or negative) $~n,~$ you have that $~e^{i\theta} = e^{i(\theta + 2n\pi)}.$

So, the satisfying value of $~z~$ will actually be represented by the set of complex numbers:

$$\ln(r) + [i(\theta + 2n\pi)] ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z}.$$